# Does the C# Compiler optimize nested property calls into inline calls?

Tags: .net, optimization, properties

So in .NET I know it is more expensive to get the value of a property than that of a field, provided that the property has some sort of logic in the getter. My question is sort of two fold. Consider the following example:

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
    item.SomeField = StaticClass.PropertyA.PropertyB.PropertyC;
}
```

So (hopefully obviously) `StaticClass` is a static class, and all of the properties to the right of that are instances of some class. Furthermore, all of the properties are purely wrappers of fields, such that `PropertyA` has a getter that merely returns a field and a setter that assigns to said field, and so on.

It can be seen by stepping through this execution that, in order to retrieve the value, three method calls must be made (`get_PropertyA()`, `get_PropertyB()`, `get_PropertyC()`). The first question I have is:

**Does the compiler optimize this expansion to only evaluate those three method calls once (ie inline their bodies)? Or will it make three method calls for every iteration?**

I would be lead to believe that the latter is true.

Furthermore, let's assume that this particular piece of code is used rampantly throughout the application. If the latter is true, would it make sense to try to optimize the method itself by storing the value of `PropertyC` before entering the loop in a local variable, and using that local variable within the loop?

Thanks in advance. This question does lean on the side of discussion, but I'm confident there is a definitive answer.

Comment: Holy Law of Demeter, Batman!

Comment: Have you actually generated the IL and looked at what the compiler does? Also, this seems like a micro-optimization.

Comment: Well that's part of the question is a) is it actually an optimization and b) is it worth it. And thanks for the LoD thing, although I think its a little speculative (I did only provide an ambiguous version of what's actually happening).

Comment: Also, why the down vote? I don't think this question shows lack of research, vagueness, or promotes discussion. The title was bad, yes.

Comment: It is one of the Great Myths of .NET programming.  Properties are **not** more expensive than fields.  The jitter optimizes the getter and setter methods, inlining them so the ultimate machine code is exactly the same as a field access.  Aimlessly optimizing code without profiling it first is a waste of time.

Comment: A better question is "what makes the jitter not inline calls". That question has probably been answered several times on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET memory model requires that the operation be evaluated once for every iteration of the loop. If you know the result of `StaticClass.PropertyA.PropertyB.PropertyC` is a constant value (or at least constant through that loop), you should declare a field outside the loop to hold its value.

```
var value = StaticClass.PropertyA.PropertyB.PropertyC;
foreach (var item in collection)
    item.SomeProperty = value;
```